# Unable to import from sequelize with esm in tests using Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sequelize.js, es6-modules

I have a express + sequelize project using ESM and I'm having troubles with sequelize imports in my tests.
I've followed [Jest guide for ESM](https://jestjs.io/fr/docs/ecmascript-modules) and it works  fine but as soon as I add tests for files importing from sequelize I get this kind of error:

> The requested module 'sequelize' does not provide an export named 'Model'

Here the error comes from a model file with this import

```js
// Mission.js
import { Model, Sequelize } from "sequelize";

export default (sequelize) => {
    class Mission extends Model {...}
    ...
    return Mission;
}
```

I run my tests using this command `NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest` as stated in Jest esm doc.

My Jest config looks like this

```js
// jest.config.js
export default {
    rootDir: "src",
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setupTests.js"],
    transform: {},
};
```

`setupTests.js` includes some beforeEach/afterEach for opening and closing db connection.

Using vscode I can CTRL + click on `Model` in the sequelize import and I can see the definition so I know it's there and the project run without problem when running
`nodemon index.js`

I'm not sure if I'm doing something worng or missed something or if it's just Jest and/or sequelize that are still not up to date with esm.

Comment: Ended up using `import Sequelize from "sequelize"` in my project. It does work now but I was kinda annoyed that I had to change my code for my tests to work

Comment: @MortezaE Thank you for the comment and the link. But I'm not sure this is related as I use only ESM import/export. Could you please elaborate on why you think this answer could help?
As mentionned in my reply `import { Model, Sequelize } from "sequelize"` does not work  in my tests but `import Sequelize from "sequelize"` does.